# SQL query for max date value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help writing this query to get all records where type is 401 unless the newest records type is 400.  ID 16 is an example of the records that are throwing me off.  Im sure this is easy and im over thinking it but I have been stuck on this for a few days now.  please help.

```
PK  ID  Type  Changeddate
1   10  400   9/30/15 20:08
2   11  401   10/7/15 18:55
3   11  401   10/7/15 18:55
4   12  400   10/9/15 20:08
5   12  400   10/9/15 20:08
6   13  401   10/14/15 14:12
7   13  401   10/14/15 14:12
8   13  400   10/15/15 15:06
9   13  400   10/15/15 15:06
10  14  401   10/26/15 17:08
11  14  401   10/26/15 17:08
12  15  401   10/29/15 3:48
13  15  401   10/29/15 3:48
14  15  400   10/29/15 19:52
15  16  400   12/29/15 13:04
16  16  400   12/29/15 13:04
17  16  401   12/29/15 13:04
18  16  401   12/29/15 13:04
19  16  400   12/29/15 13:42
20  16  400   12/29/15 13:42
```

Comment: you should also tag the database being used

Comment: how do you want to handle cases where there is a tie, e.g. PK id rows 15-18 (assuming PK id rows 19 and 20 do not exist)?

Comment: If the newest record's type *is* `400`, do you want that record to be returned, or nothing, so, with your example, for `ID` 16, do you want to get back the row with `PK` 19/20 or nothing?

Comment: Adding some expected output would probably help others to understand what it is that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is a sql server database.  Database name is adminstudio.  If the newest record is 400 i do not want it to return.  What i would like to see returned is just PK and newest date it was at 401 unless its newest date was 400.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, you can use the `last_value` window function:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        ,       last_value(Type) over (
                    partition by ID 
                    order by Changeddate
                    rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
                    as last_type
        from    YourTable yt1
        where   Type in (400, 401)
        ) sub
where   last_type <> 400
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88483/1/0)

Comment: Will the subquery return multiple rows in some cases?

Comment: @mikey: Good point, I'll add an aggregate. Would be a better query with window functions for sure.

Comment: That seems to work for the most part.  I am randomly getting items that do not fall out of the query when set back to 400.  The database we are using is a sql server database.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide an example where the query doesn't work as you expect?  Perhaps using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: TYPE      date
    401  12/15/15 18:34
    401  12/15/15 18:34
    400  12/29/15 13:04
    400  12/29/15 13:04
    401  12/29/15 13:04
    401  12/29/15 13:04
    400  12/29/15 13:42
    400  12/29/15 13:42
    401  12/29/15 15:04
    401  12/29/15 15:04
    400  12/30/15 12:32
    400  12/30/15 12:32
    306  12/30/15 12:34
    90    12/30/15 12:47

Comment: @Andomar  Sorry my example of the data is all messed up i am new to this forum and having trouble formating in the comments section.  this is a subset of data for just a certain ID.  so i omitted the ID field and PK field.  but this is an id that shows up in the query results even though on 12/30/15 12:32 the value was 400 and there were no longer any 401.  Sorry for my inexperience and poor formatting.

Comment: Ok, updated answer for SQL Server. The subquery finds the last 400 or 401 entry for the current ID.